# What are Jagged Arrays in .NET?

Tags: .net, jagged-arrays

I am learning .NET and i have seen the word "Jagged Arrays".
So i want to know that what is the perfect meaning for that.

I am just a beginner in .NET technology so please provide a specific answer for that.
If possible please explain with example.

Have a Nice Day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be this answer help to you.....

Jagged Array is an array, with each of its element as an array. Each of its element can be of different size or dimension.

Suppose, in below code we are declaring an array having 3 elements, and each of its element is an array itself, and they are of different size..

Eg:

```
int[][] x = new int[3][];
x[0] = new int[1];
x[1] = new int[10];
x[2] = new int[15];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an array of arrays, where the sub-arrays may have different sizes. For example:

```
string[][] jagged = new string[][] {
    new string[] { "one" },
    new string[] { "two", "elements" },
    new string[] { "this", "has", "three" },
};
```

Compare that with a *rectangular* array, which doesn't have "sub-arrays" but is just a genuine two-dimensional single array:

```
string[,] rectangular = new string[,] {
    // These must all have the same length
    { "a", "b" },
    { "c", "d" },
    { "0", "1" }
};
```

Comment: To add on this, I'd like to point that in C / C++ this is equivalent to making a pointer to a pointer: `int **foo = new int*[n]`. Then initializing all n array locations to point to a `new int[m_i]`, where m_i is the size of the subarray inside of foo[i].

Answer (score 2):

Jagged Array is an "Array of Arrays". More information at MSDN specific to .Net:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the microsoft msdn library, it has loads of small examples and explains them perfectly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

"A jagged array is an array whose elements are arrays. The elements of a jagged array can be of different dimensions and sizes."

Answer (score 1):

A jagged array is an array of arrays (specifically a one dimensional array of one dimensional arrays).

The term "jagged" comes from that the inner arrays can be of diffent length, compared to a two dimensional array where the data in each dimension is always the same length.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.